# Spring Boot static resources are not available

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Files in `resources/static` are not available. How I can fix it?

Hierarchy:

```
resources/
    db/
    static/
        image.png
    templates/
    application.properties
```

But if I open `localhost:8081/image.png` I get error.

My WebConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
            .addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/webjars/");
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you run it?

Comment: What is .addResourceLocations("/webjars/");?

Comment: @Adya I use bootstrap in some templates. `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7</version>
        </dependency>`

Comment: @diginoise `docker-compose up`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add below line to your existing resource mapping:

```
 registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
            .addResourceLocations("resources/static/");
```

You have configured the webjars resourceHandler to serve client side script or stylesheet dependencies. but custom handler is not added to serve your image file.

Since you are overriding the `addResourceHandlers (ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)` method, you should provide all the resourceLocation and handler mapping in your implementation.

Please check [serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot) article to have more clear idea.

**Note:**

If you are using spring-boot you shouldn't be overriding the above method untill explicitly required as its already taken care in [`WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java).

Please check below default implementation:

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        if (!this.resourceProperties.isAddMappings()) {
            logger.debug("Default resource handling disabled");
            return;
        }
        Duration cachePeriod = this.resourceProperties.getCache().getPeriod();
        CacheControl cacheControl = this.resourceProperties.getCache()
                .getCachecontrol().toHttpCacheControl();
        if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/webjars/**")) {
            customizeResourceHandlerRegistration(registry
                    .addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                    .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/")
                    .setCachePeriod(getSeconds(cachePeriod))
                    .setCacheControl(cacheControl));
        }
        String staticPathPattern = this.mvcProperties.getStaticPathPattern();
        if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern(staticPathPattern)) {
            customizeResourceHandlerRegistration(
                    registry.addResourceHandler(staticPathPattern)
                            .addResourceLocations(getResourceLocations(
                                    this.resourceProperties.getStaticLocations()))
                            .setCachePeriod(getSeconds(cachePeriod))
                            .setCacheControl(cacheControl));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here give path of your image:

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("file:/path/to/your/image/");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would prefer to serve static content (including web pages, js, pdf, css, pdf, doc etc.) from outside of the WAR, may be that is usefull. if you wanna changed any that static contents, just you can put changed file to your content path on application server easly and serving that without deploying or restarting you application server. If you prefer this way, you can do it with a small configuration on your application server.